# Finding txt files inside a given folder with subfolders?

Tags: vb.net

Can anyone tell me how can I find say *.txt files inside a given folder inside which there are subfolders in the structure **12345\30123\128\txt\100.txt**, the main folder can contain other subfolders or txt files but I only want to get the txt files which reside in the subfolders of the format **12345\30123\128\txt\100.txt**. i.e. txt files inside all **txt** folders

I have tried this:

```
Dim txtFilesArray As String() = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

But it gets all txt files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim txtFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(targetDirectory,"*.txt",SearchOption.AllDirectories)
          .Where(Function(f) f Like "*\#*\#*\#*\txt\#*.txt")
```

where `#` matches any digit from 0 to 9 and `*` matches any 0 or more characters

or slower `RegEx` version will be something like

```
Dim txtFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(targetDirectory,"*.txt",SearchOption.AllDirectories)
          .Where(Function(f) RegEx.IsMatch(f, ".*\\\d+\\\d+\\\d+\\txt\\\\d+\.txt"))

For Each txtFile In txtFiles 
    '...
Next
```

Comment: The folder names in the structure **12345\30123\128\txt\100.txt** could be different, like the first folder instead of being a five digit name it could be a six digit name or four digit name and same goes for all the subfolders is well, can I use like  `(\d+)\(\d+)\(\d+)\txt\(\d+).txt` instead of `*####\#####\###\txt\###.txt` with the exact same code?

Comment: @Don_B the `Like` operator doesn't support that but I updated my answer to match a digit and any number of characters after it `#*`. I am not sure if the `RegEx` version will work.

Comment: What matches a hyphen "-" character in `Like` operator?

Comment: @Don_B `-` or `[-]` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much for helping!!

Comment: @Don_B np. With `.EnumerateFiles` you can use the found results before the search finishes if you use it without the `.ToArray`

Comment: Do you mind checking out this post and possibly help me [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39188840/how-to-match-multiple-regex-patterns-in-multiple-files-and-write-something-to-a

Answer (score 0):

This will return all files but those contained at `path`:

```
Dim path = "C:\"
Dim di As New DirectoryInfo(path)
Dim files = di _
    .GetFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories) _
    .Where(Function(info) info.DirectoryName <> path) _
    .Select(function(info) info.FullName) _
    .ToArray()
```