# How to match multiple regex patterns in multiple files and write something to a log file?

Tags: regex, vb.net

I want to search some regex patterns in files (*.txt) which are inside a folder whose path I'have given in a text box, and the folder contains other sub-folders with txt files in the form 12345\2031\30201\txt\120.txt and if the pattern matches even in one file, then a string is written on a log file which is created inside the folder whose path I've given in the text box and then it moves on to the next regex and so on
What I've done so far is

```
Dim tLoc As String = TextBox1.Text
        Dim txtFilesArray = Directory.EnumerateFiles(tLoc, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(Function(f) f Like "*\#*\#*\#*\txt\#*.txt")
        Dim fileLoc As String = tLoc & "\Checklist.log"
        Dim fs As FileStream = Nothing
        If (Not File.Exists(fileLoc)) Then
            fs = File.Create(fileLoc)
            Using fs

            End Using
        End If
        For Each tFile In txtFilesArray
            Dim input As String = File.ReadAllText(tFile)
            Dim pattern1 As New Regex("(?<!>)(figure|fig\.|figs\.|figures) (\d+)")
            Dim pattern2 As New Regex("(?<!>)(table|tab\.|tabs\.|tables) (\d+)")
            If pattern1.IsMatch(input) Then
                FileOpen(1, fileLoc, OpenMode.Append)
                PrintLine(1, "Check figure link")
                FileClose()
            End If
            If pattern2.IsMatch(input) Then
                FileOpen(1, fileLoc, OpenMode.Append)
                PrintLine(1, "Check table link")
                FileClose()
            End If

        Next
```

But the problems are:
1) Even if `pattern1` matches in multiple files, I want it to write the string **Check figure link** only once in the log file and not in every time it finds a match in different files and same for *pattern2....patternN*, furthermore, I want the program to move on to the next regex pattern match the moment the `pattern1` matches in one file (no need to look for the same pattern in other files)
2)I have around a hundred of regex patterns that I want to use in this program, can anyone tell me how do I shorten the coding?

Comment: Sounds like a programming thing, not a regex thing. You could remove the `regex` tag, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the patterns in some kind of collection and then remove them from it when found

```
Dim re = Function(p$) New Regex(p, RegexOptions.Compiled)
Dim patterns = New Dictionary(Of String, Regex) From {
    {"Check figure link", re("(?<!>)(figure|fig\.|figs\.|figures) (\d+)")},
    {"Check table link", re("(?<!>)(table|tab\.|tabs\.|tables) (\d+)")}
}
Dim output = New List(Of String)
Dim tLoc = TextBox1.Text
Dim txtFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(tLoc, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)

For Each tFile In txtFiles
    If Not tFile Like "*\#*\#*\#*\txt\#*.txt" Then Continue For
    Dim input = File.ReadAllText(tFile)

    Dim match = ""
    For Each pattern In patterns
        If pattern.Value.IsMatch(input) Then
            match = pattern.Key
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If match > "" Then
        output.Add(match)
        patterns.Remove(match)
    End If
Next
File.WriteAllLines(tLoc.TrimEnd("\"c) & "\Checklist.log", output)
```

If you want to compare each pattern against all files, then it will be easier to parallelize (run on multiple processors at the same time) because there will be no need to remove them from the collection:

```
Dim patterns = New List(Of String()) From {
    ({"Check figure link", "(?<!>)(figure|fig\.|figs\.|figures) (\d+)"}),
    ({"Check table link", "(?<!>)(table|tab\.|tabs\.|tables) (\d+)"})}

Parallel.ForEach(patterns,
    Sub(pattern)
        Dim tLoc = TextBox1.Text
        Dim output = New List(Of String)
        Dim txtFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(tLoc, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        Dim regEx = New Regex(pattern(1), RegexOptions.Compiled)

        For Each tFile In txtFiles
            If tFile Like "*\#*\#*\#*\txt\#*.txt" Then
                Dim input = File.ReadAllText(tFile)
                If regEx.IsMatch(input) Then
                    output.Add(pattern(0))
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next
        File.AppendAllLines(TextBox1.Text.TrimEnd("\"c) & "\Checklist.log", output)
    End Sub)
```

or this shorter more complicated version

```
Dim patterns = New List(Of String()) From {
    ({"Check figure link", "(?<!>)(figure|fig\.|figs\.|figures) (\d+)"}),
    ({"Check table link", "(?<!>)(table|tab\.|tabs\.|tables) (\d+)"})}

Dim output = From pattern In patterns.AsParallel
             Let regEx = New Regex(pattern(1), RegexOptions.Compiled)
             From tFile In Directory.EnumerateFiles(TextBox1.Text, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
             Where tFile Like "*\#*\#*\#*\txt\#*.txt" AndAlso regEx.IsMatch(File.ReadAllText(tFile))
             Take 1
             Select pattern(0)

File.WriteAllLines(TextBox1.Text.TrimEnd("\"c) & "\Checklist.log", output)
```

Comment: The first coding shows an exception `Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in mscorlib.dll`

Comment: @Don_B oh I think the problem is because I am removing in inside of the loop. I will update the sample later

Comment: Could you please explain your "shorter more complicated version" code, how it works? I'm completely lost on it...
Thnx in advance.

Comment: @Don_B you can do internet search for "`VB LINQ`" and check some of the examples. The `From` is similar to a `For Each` loop, `Let` similar to `Dim`,  `Where` to `If` statement, `Take 1` is to take just the first item, and `Select` is similar to adding the found items to a collection. Did you try all 3 of the examples? I am curious if the parallel versions were any faster.

Comment: I did try all 3 of the examples on my few sample files, however I did not notice any difference in process speed as I was just matching the two patterns I posted on smaller files. Once I try it on larger files with 100 regex patterns then I think I will be able to see which process works faster.
Anyways, thank a lot....

Comment: I didn't realize this, but there seems to be a problem in the code which is the log file only writes "Check figure link" in files where both the regex `(?<!>)(figure|fig\.|figs\.|figures) (\d+)"` and `(?<!>)(table|tab\.|tabs\.|tables) (\d+)` matches?